# Will packet sniffing still work if all connections go through a local proxy?

Tags: http, sniffer, wireshark

Will packet sniffing work if all connections use a local proxy? 
You are forced to use this proxy to get a connection to the internet at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting through a local proxy you should normally still be able to sniff all your own outgoing packets.

Comment: Will I only be able to sniff my own outgoing packets?

Comment: Well that would depend on your physical infrastructure, if you are connecting through wireless or a hub you will still be able to see traffic passing on there.

Comment: Ah so if I connect through wireless, I will be able to see all traffic through that router?

Comment: not through that router but on the same wireless network